# Problemas con Godot

Tags: motor-de-juego

Hola tengo un problema instale Godot 3.1.1 de 32Bits y me sale el siguiente error

> your video card driver does not support any og the supported OpenGL
>   version. Place update your drivers or if you have a very old or
>   integrated GPU upgrade it.

Tengo una tarjeta integrada intel Q45/Q43 Express Chipset, el tipo es una intel 4 Series Express Chipset Family.
tengo esta tarjeta integrada ya que estoy ejecutandolo desde una Netbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actualiza el controlador de la tarjeta, no mencionas el sistema operativo pero por lo que veo en la página de descargas de Intel (https://downloadcenter.intel.com/es/download/21831/controlador-de-gr-ficos-Intel-para-Windows-XP-64-bit-exe-?product=81511) la tarjeta de video es un poco veterana y lo más seguro es que tenga incompatibilidades.

Trata de ejecutar Godot con una versión anterior de OpenGL utilizando el parámetro `--video-driver` desde una consola:
`Godot_v3.1-stable_win64.exe --video-driver GLES2`

Si quieres ver todos los parámetros ejecuta:
`Godot_v3.1-stable_win64.exe --help`